# delete blank space of crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building a report with Crystal Reports.
So I have a section that can have the value from a table. This section writes the result of a query and can have 1, 2 , 3 , , N row.

I have set this setting of this values:

[image]

[image]

If the column does not have a value, I don't display the result and this is ok, but the report shows the blank space. How can I delete this blank space ?

> EDIT
>   The result of my Table5 can be never record or more record. I want to suppres the blank space if the Table5 not have record
>
> EDIT 2
>   This is the detail section:
>   [image]

I want to delete the part

```
Parametro | Valore | U.M. | Valori di riferimento
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value is only white space, or more precisely, only contains `space`-characters, you can use the `Trim`-function.

```
Trim({Table5.Colonna1})
```

or when you want to suppress the field if it's just white space, put this in the suppression-formula:

```
Trim({Table5.Colonna1})=""
```

---

**EDIT**

To get rid of the blank part:

- Create a new `DetailSection` below the existing one.
- Move the fields `Colonna1`, `Colonna2`, `Colonna3`, `Colonna4` and the belonging headers to the new section.
- Edit the suppression-formula of the new `DetailSection` and insert the following formula

**formula**

```
If IsNull({Table5.Colonna1}) And IsNull({Table5.Colonna2}) And
   IsNull({Table5.Colonna3}) And IsNull({Table5.Colonna4}) Then
    True
Else
    False
```

If `Colonna1`, `Colonna2`, `Colonna3` and `Colonna4` can not contain the value `NULL` inside the database, you could only query one of them and shorten the suppression-formula like following (the same as in your printscreen):

```
IsNull({Table5.Colonna1})
```

Comment: I have try to use your function but the black space is visible

Comment: I have just EDIT my questions. My resultset can be with never record or more record. I want to suppress blank space if the resultset not containes record

Comment: So you want to suppress the whole detail-section, not the field? Is the value `NULL` or is it white space? Maybe the `suppress blank section` option would work...please be more specific.